# How can I construct $H$ and $G$ such that $T \circ G=0$ and $H \circ T=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need your help to complete my proof please. This is what I've to prove:

> Let be $F$ a fied, $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, and
> a lineal operator $T:V \rightarrow V$ distinct to zero and not
> invertible. Prove that there exists $G$ and $H$ lineal operations in
> $V$ distinct to zero sush that: $T \circ G = 0$ and $H \circ T = 0$

**My attempt:**

As we know that $T$ is not injective, then $Ker(T) \neq \left \{ 0 \right \}$. Let be $\mathcal{B}=\left \{ e_1,e_2...,e_k,...e_n \right \}$ a basis of $V$, such that $\mathcal{B}_{W_T}=\left \{ e_1,...,e_k \right \}$ is a basis of the subspace $W_T=Ker(T)$. So if we define $G:V \rightarrow W_T$, it satisfies $\forall \alpha \in V$ that $(T \circ G) \alpha = 0$.

By the other side, we have also that $T$ is not invertible so that implies that $T$ is not surjective. So, $T:V \rightarrow W_H$, with $W_H \subset V$. We can construct $H$ a linear operator such that $W_H=Ker(H)$. So, it would satisfies $(H \circ T)\alpha=0$ for any $\alpha \in V$.

**My doubt:**

Is it necessary to construct $H$ and $G$ with that characteristics to complete my proof? Or is it enough to name those properties. I think that it is neccesary to construct them explicitly but I don't know how, *can you help me please to construct them*?

Comment: Those are well defined linear operator so you proved existence. As for construction maybe it could help trying to find $H,G$ as in your process with an easy example like $dim(V)=2$ and $F$ the reals.

Comment: What is necessary in a proof depends on the intended audience. For a homework assignment, the more you include, the better. For a research paper in a mathematical journal, the less you include, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Choose $k$ distinct integers $i_1,\dots,i_k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and define the linear map $G : V \to V$ by sending $e_{i_j}$ to $e_j$ (for $j=1,\dots,k$) and the others $n-k$ basis vectors to $0$. For example, $$G(e_1)=e_1,\dots,G(e_k)=e_k,G(e_{k+1})=0,\dots,G(e_n)=0.$$
- Since $T \neq 0$ and $T$ is not surjective, $\operatorname{im} T$ is a proper nonzero subspace of $V$. Thus, we can find a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ for $V$ such that $v_1,\dots,v_l$ $(l< n)$ is a basis for $\operatorname{im} T$. Now define the linear map $H : V \to V$ by sending $v_1,\dots,v_l$ to $0$ and the others $n-l$ basis vectors not all to $0$.